# Combine tinywatermark and jquery ui datepicker plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, watermark

I have the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3rHRM/) that have on the same input field tinywatermark and jquery ui datepicker plugins.

But they are not working together. the datepicker doesn't open.

How can I do to make them work together?

I think that the problem is because the `clone` function in the tinywatermark plugin.
This is the [tinywatermark plugin](http://www.weblap.ro/res/tinywatermark/jquery.tinywatermark-3.1.0.js)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tinywatermark is cloning the original input and replacing it with that clone. Thats why dateinput isn't working there any more. You can try to use something like this:

```
$('input')
    .datepicker()
    .on('blur', function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).val('choose date');
        }
    })
    .on('focus', function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'choose date') {
            $(this).val('');
        }
    })
    .trigger('blur');
```

Comment: Thanks... this is the update fiddle... with the title attr.. http://jsfiddle.net/3rHRM/2/

Answer (score 2):

If you do not require the 'watermark' to be visible in obsolete browsers, you can use the html tag 'placeholder' in your input and remove the watermark-plugin:

```
<input type='text' id='test' value='' placeholder='choose date' />
```

You could also use a jQuery plugin that does not make a clone, but does polyfill the placeholder behaviour, this one for example: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder